# what is the way to display multiple images at the same level?

Tags: html, css

```
body{
background-size: 100%;
background-image:url('../img/back.png');
}
.school{
font-size:45px;
margin: 20px 20px;
color:#696969;
font-weight:600;
}
.date{
font-size:28px;
width:200px;
height:40px;
color:#696969;
font-weight:600;
margin-left:70%;
  }
  #mid{
  }
  .kid_info{
  width:242px;
  height:162px;
  background:url('../img/bubble_info.png') no-repeat;
  padding: 20px 40px;
  }
  #name{
  font-size:30px;
  color:#696969;
  }
 .kid_info font{
  font-size:18px;
  color:#808080;
  }
  .kid_pic{
  width:40px;
  height:200px;
  background:url('../img/kid.png') no-repeat;
  }
  .grap{
width:629px;
height:394px;
background:url('../img/mon_folder.png') no-repeat;
  }




  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
  <html>

  <body>
 <div class="school">Willdow Glen Elementary</div>
 <div class="date">February-Week2</div>
 <div id="mid">
 <div class="kid_info"><font id="name">Jack Nicklaus</font></br><font>Age. 8</font>     
 </br><font>Gender.male</font></div>
 <div class="kid_pic"></div>
 <div class="graph"></div>
 </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I am trying to display three images at the same level It seems like three images are not well displayed at the same level three images I am very beginner of css. Please give me some advice Thank you advance

Comment: Please provide your HTML so we can see where the css is applying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display three images at the same with out using CSS. You can do this using the tables as follows.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td><img src="image1.jpg" name=""/></td>
<td><img src="image2.jpg" name=""/></td>
<td><img src="image3.jpg" name=""/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Try like this. Then you can use CSS to more beautification.